# SQL Union: merge select results with direct values

Tags: sql

In my data model I have "parts" and "components", being the relation between them N:M. One part can be used in 0:N components, one component may use 0:N parts.

I want to prepare an SQL to search for "part" rows, either by part ID or component ID. (I know this is not optimal, but these are my conditions right now).

So, my first attempt tries to use UNION (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

```
SELECT *
FROM part
WHERE part.id IN (
    ('abc', 'def') -- IDs of parts
    UNION (  -- IDs of parts that correspond to components with those IDs
        select part.id
        from component
        ... joins for the many-to-many: component-component2part-part
        where component.id in ('abc', 'def') -- same values as before
    )
)
```

This query crashes, probably because the left part of the UNION clause is not the result of a query, but the direct values `('abc', 'def')`, and it can't be merged with the result of the subquery.

My workaround for the moment is:

```
SELECT *
FROM part
WHERE (
    part.id IN ('abc', 'def') -- IDs of parts
    OR
    part.id IN ( -- IDs of parts that correspond to components with those IDs
        select part.id
        from component
        ... joins for the many-to-many: component-component2part-part
        where componend.id in ('abc', 'def') -- same values as before
    )
)
```

And voilà it works, but probably this is not the most efficient way to do this. Any idea or hint? Thanks in advance.

The query should work with SQL Server, Oracle and SQLite

Comment: Your "workaround" seems simple and straightforward enough for me – the kind of solution I would always stick to from the beginning unless its potential to cause performance issues was more or less obvious. *Are* you experiencing performance issues with your query? In any event, optimising for performance is also platform specific more often than not, so, in the end you might need to ask for an optimised solution separately for every mentioned platform. (But, as I said, please first make sure you've establish that your present solution *is* inefficient for that particular platform.)

Comment: You are right, I better first check the performance and then decide whether or not to optimize. But appart from better perfomance, I also was looking for a possible better or more succint way of expressing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have an id 'abc' which could be the id of a part, the id of a component or both. And you want the part info for the parts 'abc' and the part info for parts with a component 'abc'.

Based on that understanding, you want the list of parts with matching ids and the list of parts with components with those same ids. Then just union them together.

```
select p.*
from   part p
where  p.id in( 'abc', 'def' )
union
select p.*
from   component c
join   part2components pc
  on   pc.Component_id = c.id
join   part p
  on   p.id = pc.Part_id
where  c.id in( 'abc', 'def' );
```

Comment: This is right. Do you know anything about the (general) performance of this against my method? thanks

Comment: Not from just eye-balling it. You'd want to compare optimizer plans generated from your actual tables and possibly run both with timing stats. I'm going to guess mine will be a little better just because I've had some bad experiences with subqueries in an `in` and `exists` clauses. Also, mine is a little more maintainable as it breaks out the selection criteria into separate standard queries instead of mixing them together. It took me a while to "see" what your query was doing. Have some sympathy for the poor developer who has to maintain the code after you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many IDs in first set, second approach is the best one.
Else you can do

```
SELECT 'abc'
UNION
SELECT 'def'
UNION (
    select part.id
    from component
    ...
)
```